# Does Postgres hstore support atomic updates per element?

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, atomic, hstore

Or do you have to update lets say an entire collection/array in a hstore column?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "atomic"? You can remove and add individual elements if that is what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, on both counts.

First updates are "atomic" in the ACID sense.  Secondly, you can reference the old variable values in your new definition, so yes on that count.

The only caveat is that because of the way MVCC works each update creates a *copy* that is only visible after the transaction commits.  That doesn't seem to my mind to go against atomicity though.